# Forfiles batch command produces error

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt

I'm trying to create a batch file to delete temp files. However when running the bat it errors with:

> "The specified directory does not exist"

This is the batch file:

```
REM Deletes files older than 7 days old

forfiles -p "C:\Users\wtsadmin\AppData\Local\Trend Micro\OSDP\wtsadmin@workingtime%2Dsolutions.com\temp" /s /m *.tmp /D -7 /C "cmd /c del @PATH"
pause
```

The path is definitely correct as I've tested it and was copied and pasted from explorer anyway.

I've scoured the Internet try to find a solution, but as far as I can see the commands and syntax is correct?

Answer (score 0):

```
....time%2Dsolu....
        ^^
        second argument to batch file?
```

If the path contains a percent sign, you will need to escape it inside the batch file

```
....time%%2Dsolu....
```

Comment: Thanks very much

Ok, made the change, but now it's producing a "The parameter is incorrect" error???

Comment: @Amer, if you remove the full `/C "cmd ..."` to only get the list of files, does it still generate the error?

Comment: I think `%2D` is representing a character like a `-`.

Comment: C:\Users\wtsadmin\Desktop>REM Deletes files older than 7 days old

C:\Users\wtsadmin\Desktop>forfiles /p "C:\Users\wtsadmin\AppData\Local\Trend Mic
ro\OSDP\wtsadmin@workingtime%2Dsolutions.com\temp" /s /m *.* /d -7

"1406EF0.tmp"
"1504CA5.tmp"
ERROR: The parameter is incorrect.
"190C166.tmp"
"BabD631.tmp"
ERROR: The parameter is incorrect.
"CCC3884.tmp"
"CCC6EDF.tmp"
"CCC966D.tmp"
ERROR: The parameter is incorrect.

Comment: "CCCE594.tmp"
"CCCE5B4.tmp"
"CGO196B.tmp"
"Day170A.tmp"
"Emp5C20.tmp"
"FS-4B4.tmp"
ERROR: The parameter is incorrect.
"FS-97F4.tmp"
"FS-AA57.tmp"
"InsBF43.tmp"
"MCAC0D.tmp"
"PfiE3C9.tmp"
"V8 B41.tmp"
"WarA93D.tmp"
"WORC0C8.tmp"
"WORD9A6.tmp"
"WORE38.tmp"

C:\Users\wtsadmin\Desktop>pause
Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: I was going to post a screen shot of the Command line window, but there doesn't seem to be that option here?